# Citing "p. x" to mean page ten of a book looks confusing since "x" isn't clearly a Roman Numeral

Tags: citations, citation-style

By theory, I should cite `page x` (page ten) like `[Krusche1999, p. x]`. If it were on `page iii` or `page xi`, it would look better, such as `[Krusche1999, p. iii]` or `[Krusche1999, p. xi]`. However, it is on `page x`, so we end up with `p. x`. At least to me, I won't understand, what `p. x` means at first sight. What do you think? Any good ideas?

Comment: Ah, it took me a few seconds to understand this is a problem similar to the 4th subsection of section 10 in APS style, i.e., Sec. XD

Comment: To me, "p. x" seems more or less as understandable as "p. xi".  In isolation, "x" wouldn't look as obviously like a Roman numerical, but after "p." I don't see any other plausible interpretation.  So I wouldn't worry about this (but maybe other people would find it weirder than I would).

Comment: This suggests an interesting possibility for my next paper: "We refer the reader to [Krusche1999, p. x], where x is the solution of equation (17)".

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: I disagree: An *x* at any place where a number (or a title, or something) is expected inherently makes me think "Someone forgot to look up the exact page and substitute the placeholder in their camera-ready version." as the most plausible interpretation. That said, I am totally in favour of writing "p. x" nonetheless, as a page reference is only irrelevant eye-candy for readers who don't actually look for the page in the source, and readers who do will immediately find out what is meant by *x*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper has the right idea - besides, if the page number really is "x" you don't have a lot of choice. This should be a rare occurrence anyway as (lower case) roman page numbering is generally used for front matter which doesn't tend to contain anything worth citing (anything in the abstract could be better cited from a more detailed part of the work).

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, roman numbering system is usually used to number pages before the main part of the book. But I did want to cite a sentence in the prelude.

Comment: If the style guide doesn't otherwise say, you could put the Roman numerals in italics. Many books do that anyways. Plus, because it's italicized, to me, it would stand out more as a "I intentionally put x".

Comment: @guifa Bad idea. By default (and following ISO standards), LaTeX typesets all mathematical variables in italics.  So at least in communities that use LaTeX, setting the x in italics ("p. _x_") suggests more strongly that x is a variable—that is, a placeholder—than setting it upright ("p. x").

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't be veering from the style guide (you are of course following a style guide, right?), and style guides cover such meticulous points as this. Even if you feel their advice is a little off and you might have a better solution to a readability problem, you should never contradict it. (Why you should not contradict it is a lengthier topic, and I think this answer stands without going into it.)

So, the right thing to do is consult your respective style guide whether it's AMA or Chicago or anything else, and do what it says.

Comment: Maybe this is field-specific (and I think so, because this has repeatedly struck as very unusual when reading some remarks here on Academia SE), but at least in the areas of CS I am acquainted with, "style guides cover such meticulous points as this" is absolutely not true. I am used to styleguides that cover (if at all) a few very common issues and simply do not make any statements about any of the less usual cases.

Comment: Style guides for the journals I've written for don't go into anything like this level of detail either.

Comment: I agree that this is not only field-specific but venue-specific.  You use a style guide if you're targeting a particular publication venue that requires that particular style.  Some style guides are strict, some are flexible; some journals/editors are strict about making you adhere to the style guide, some are flexible.  I don't think the issue raised in this particular question is a major one, but I think in many cases it is absolutely appropriate to contradict a style guide if adhering to it will make something more confusing.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on AAA's answer, the correct answer to any question about citation style is always "check with the guidelines of the journal in question." To give one example, the Chicago Manual of Style [clearly lists how to cite introductory page numbers](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/717/03). Your journal will link to something similar; check their documentation and do whatever they say.

Comment: If the journal's style guide covers such points, your answer is perfect. But I don't recall coming across a journal in my own field (theoretical comp. sci.) where the style guides go into anything like this level of detail.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Good point. Many journals (where "many" is completely unquantified) will simply say "use APA style" or "use IEEE style", which simplifies things. However, if a journal tries to "roll their own", then yeah, that's an issue.